# Magento 2 : Check out page shipping address form Country State city sort oder

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am working on magento 2.1.3

I want to change the sort order of shipping address form elements Country State and City in checkout page.

Country should load first then State and finally city

Comment: nobody have answer..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got answer for this

Edit following file

app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

and put like this

```
 <body>   
 <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
 <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">

                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">80</item>
                                                        </item>


                                                        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">85</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">87</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">88</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">90</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```